# Regex for floating point with limited digits

Tags: regex

I need a Regex for decimal with length of 6 for example need regex to match following

```
123456.0
1.23456
12.3456
123.456
1234.56
12345.6
123456.0
```

I have tried but without success.

Comment: What were your attempts? Are you accepting `.123456` as well? Or `123456`?

Comment: "123456.0" --> how do you determine whether a number has "length of 6"? Would "123456.1" be valid?

Answer (score 0):

This matches all your examples:

```
^(?=.{7}$)\d+\.\d+$|^\d{6}\.0$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/vyjfNEK7VW) on rubular.